# Is there any method to change the swipe direction of viewPager. I want to change the fragments on swipe up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to implement to change the fragment upon swiping upwards/downwards but all solution I find on the SO is just for RTL and even they are just saying to reverse the list/fragment. I want some solid method to implement it.

These are some of the links which I tried:

1) [Changing viewPager swipe direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443558/changing-viewpager-swipe-direction)

2) [Android change default direction swipe of ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094602/android-change-default-direction-swipe-of-viewpager)

3) [how to make my viewpager swipe from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781944/how-to-make-my-viewpager-swipe-from-right-to-left)

4) [how to reverse the direction of viewPager to left to right order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489723/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-viewpager-to-left-to-right-order)

5) [Swipe Direction in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721539/swipe-direction-in-viewpager)

6) [Android OnTouch swipe up/down direction change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570917/android-ontouch-swipe-up-down-direction-change)

Comment: Another alternative would be to take a look into Google's revamped ViewPager called `ViewPager2`: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2. As far as I can tell from the javadoc, it looks there is a way to change the default orientation from horizontal to vertical with `.setOrientation(orientation)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found this somewhere in the Big Google Ocean.

Let me know if it helps you.

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction) {
        return super.canScrollHorizontally(direction);
    }

    private void init() {
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final boolean toIntercept = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(flipXY(ev));
        flipXY(ev);
        return toIntercept;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final boolean toHandle = super.onTouchEvent(flipXY(ev));
        flipXY(ev);
        return toHandle;
    }

    private MotionEvent flipXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        final float width = getWidth();
        final float height = getHeight();
        final float x = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        final float y = (ev.getX() / width) * height;
        ev.setLocation(x, y);
        return ev;
    }

    private static final class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            final int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            final int pageHeight = view.getHeight();
            if (position < -1) {
                view.setAlpha(0);
            } else if (position <= 1) {
                view.setAlpha(1);
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);
                float yPosition = position * pageHeight;
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
            } else {
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this same as you use your ViewPager. This will change it from Horizontal to Vertical .

Comment: Thanks @Derek it worked. Hey, Can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753847/i-have-webview-in-my-fragments-and-when-swiping-webview-than-viewpager-also-star